# Count of builds run per day usable as revision number substitute?

Tags: tfs-2015

Up to now I am using

```
$(Build.DefinitionName)_1.0.$(Year:yy)$(DayOfYear).$(Rev:r)
```

as the build number format for all my build definitions.

Now I have the (personal) problem when one build definition runs often per day and another only seldom does, that even if the latter one ran last, it has a lot smaller revision number than the often run build definiton which I don't like a lot.

Now I am wondering if there is some variable which holds the value of the total count of builds that were already run during the day and use that variable in my build number format instead of the revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any out of box variable to count this. You can add a powershell script task in your build definition to count the build of today and update the build number via calling [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview). Following is the script to achieve this feature(You need to enable "Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token" option in your build definition to use this script):

```
##Generate credential
$user = "any"

$pwd = $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN

$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$pwd)))

##Count build of today
$today = Get-Date

$collectionuri = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI

$project = $env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT

$uri = $collectionuri + $project + '/_apis/build/builds?api-version=2.0&minFinishTime=' + $today.ToShortDateString()

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -ContentType application/json

$buildcount = $response.count

##Update build number
$number = $buildcount + 1

$buildnumber = 'xxx.xxx.xxx.' + $number

Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$buildnumber"
```

Comment: I am getting a 401 error (Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.) at `Invoke-RestMethod...` with CategoryInfo: InvalidOperation:  (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException). Is the string `"any"` a placeholder or do I have to fill in something meaningful in my context? I have currently no access to the build machine - I can only change the build definition.

Comment: @David Did you check the "Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token" option in your build definition?

Comment: Yes, that option is checked.

Comment: @David I just noticed that you are working with On-premise TFS, not VSTS. Sorry for that. For on-premise TFS, you need to enable the basic auth and set "$user" and "$pwd" with your account name and password.

Comment: I wonder how you noticed that I have a on-premise TFS, but indeed. Thanks for the update.

Comment: @David Just because you added "tfs2015" tag. And instead of config basic auth, you can also code to "$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers @{Authorization=("Bearer {0}" -f $pwd)} -ContentType application/json".

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$(BuildId)` instead of `$(Rev:r)`.

Comment: `$(BuildId)` holds the value of the total count of builds that ran on the system generally (I guess because I got a number > 65000 which is greater than what is allowed to be set as the revision part of the version) but not **per day** unfortunately.